# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: Python

Tags: python, windows

I have a script that is called from DJango, but it doesn't execute instead it gives `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`. I'm using CMD on Windows as admin.

Here is how I'm calling:

```
cmd = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "D:/commerceTest/cs50-commerceM/Photo/GFPGAN/inference_gfpgan.py --upscale 2 --model_path D:/commerceTest/cs50-commerceM/Photo/GFPGAN/experiments/pretrained_models/ --test_path inputs/whole_imgs/GFPGANCleanv1-NoCE-C2.pth --save_root D:/commerceTest/cs50-commerceM/Photo/GFPGAN/results")
        #os.system("python D:/commerceTest/cs50-commerceM/Photo/GFPGAN/inference_gfpgan.py --upscale 2 --model_path D:/commerceTest/cs50-commerceM/Photo/GFPGAN/experiments/pretrained_models/ --test_path inputs/whole_imgs/GFPGANCleanv1-NoCE-C2.pth --save_root D:/commerceTest/cs50-commerceM/Photo/GFPGAN/results")
os.system('{} {}'.format('python', cmd))
```

Here is the message I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\commerceTest\cs50-commerceM\Photo\GFPGAN\inference_gfpgan.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\commerceTest\cs50-commerceM\Photo\GFPGAN\inference_gfpgan.py", line 52, in main
    restorer = GFPGANer(
  File "D:\commerceTest\cs50-commerceM\Photo\GFPGAN\gfpgan\utils.py", line 60, in __init__
    loadnet = torch.load(model_path)
  File "D:\Users\rapha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 594, in load
    with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
  File "D:\Users\rapha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 230, in _open_file_like
    return _open_file(name_or_buffer, mode)
  File "D:\Users\rapha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 211, in __init__
    super(_open_file, self).__init__(open(name, mode))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/commerceTest/cs50-commerceM/Photo/GFPGAN/experiments/pretrained_models/'
```

Comment: Why are you trying to join two absolute paths? Why does the second path contain CLI arguments? You should avoid using `os.system` in favor of `subprocess`.

Comment: Can you write a corresponding command in the CMD window? Does it work? What exactly does that look like? In your own words, what do you think `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ...)` does, and why is it part of your code here? In your own words, what is an *absolute path*, and what is a *relative path*? Which kind does your code currently use? What does the documentation for the `inference_gfpgan.py` script say about how to call it? In particular, does it say something about whether to use a directory or a file for the `--model_path`? Which should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess here but the error that you are getting is because Python is trying to open a directory as a file (which won't work).

It looks like the path that you are passing in to `--model_path` is a directory but [`torch.load()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html) expects a file, that would explain it.

I would start with understanding what exactly the script `inference_gfpgan.py` does and how it works.